# CSS Print media out shifts sideways on successive pages

Tags: css, firefox, printing, media

I'm printing fixed size index cards as 'DIV'.  Two fit side by side on A4 with float=left.  Works fine for the first seven pages, then on page eight, switches to single column.  So I tried float=right and that works fine as well, except that on each page, the output shifts a little to the left and (you guessed) after eight pages, single 'column' again.  Note that within each page, the DIVs all line up... they just move on successive pages. Can't show the HTML 'cos it is generated by Javascript.
The relevant CSS looks like this

```
@media print {
  .card {
    float: left;
    width: 85.6mm;
    height: 54mm;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
```

The generated HTML looks something like this

```
<div class="card">
<h2>name</h2>
lines of stuff<br />
</div>
<div ...
</div>
```

and so on.
It would seem that the right margin is being increased with each new page.
I'm running Firefox and Ubuntu.  Anyone encountered anything like this.  Bug in Firefox ?